# Using jQuery and php to pull data from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a page that is pulling data through jQuery but it is only pulling the return code. Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
function showCU() {
$.post('getCU.php', {
cuid: $('#cuContact').val()
}, 
function (response) {
$('#contact').val(response).show();
$('#email').val(response).show();
$('#phone').val(response).show();
})
}
</script>

$select = "SELECT priContact, priEmail, priPhone FROM user WHERE id = '" . $_POST['id'] . "'";
$query = mysql_query($select) or die ("Could not get info: " . mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $priContact = $get['priContact'];
    echo $priContact;
    echo $get['priEmail'] . " | " . $get['priPhone'];
    }
} else {
    echo "No users";
}
```

So the call is pulling from getCU.php whenever the onchange event handler is called. That is why this is in a function. What I want to do is every time a user chooses something from the option list the text values change according to what was selected. I have the php page pulling from a db and echoing out the code correctly. jQuery id pulling the data from the php page correctly, but I cannot get the code to place the single details in each of the text boxes.

So what I want to happen is this:
A user selects a name from a drop-down box. Then the mysql data attached to that name would be displayed on the page in form text fields.

Let me know if more information or code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off structuring your data.  My general recommendation is JSON.

```
// QUICK WARNING:  Don't take unparse GET/POST responses.  
// This is asking for trouble from SQL injection.
$select = "SELECT priContact, priEmail, priPhone FROM user WHERE id = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']) . "'";
$query = mysql_query($select) or die ("Could not get info: " . mysql_error());
$retVal = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    $retVal['data'] = array();
    while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
        $retVal['data'][] = $get;
    }
} else {
    $retVal['error'] = 'No users';
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($retVal);
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showCU() {
   $.post('getCU.php', {
       cuid: $('#cuContact').val(),
       dataType:'json'
     }, 
     function (response) {
       if (response.error) {
         //handle error
       }
       else
       {
          $('#contact').val(response.data.priContact).show();
          $('#email').val(response.data.priEmail).show();
          $('#phone').val(response.data.priPhone).show();
       }
     })
   }
</script>
```

Comment: This code is not working and I am not sure why. I am very new to jQuery and do not know JSON at all. I need to have this done in the slightest of forms ASAP. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have found that the function response is not being called so the data is a blank value. How do I fix this?